# What is the difference between なさいます and いたします?

Tags: grammar, translation, politeness

> 1. お飲み物はどう**なさいます**か。
> 2. お飲み物はどう**いたします**か。

I can't understand how one might be used instead of the other.

Comment: Please try to use specific question titles.  "What is the difference?" is not an acceptable title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

なさる, whose polite form is なさいます, is 尊敬語｛そんけいご｝ 'honorific language', whereas いたす, whose polite form is いたします, is 謙譲語｛けんじょうご｝ 'humble language'.

You would use なさる to show respect for somebody performing an action, whereas いたす humbles your own actions in respectful environments. Both are ultimately about respect, of course.

お飲み物はどうなさいますか。= 'What are you going to do about the drinks?'

お飲み物はどういたしますか。= 'What shall I do about the drinks?'

Comment: The difference between honorific and humble languages entails that in one case the (implicit) subject must be the 1st person (or assimilated) and in the other it can only be (respected) 2nd or 3rd person.

Comment: @MathieuBouville I'm pretty sure humble language can be used in reference to another person - for example, speaking of someone from your own company to a representative from another company. Maybe a native speaker can shed some light, though.

Comment: But one of my examples says コーヒーはどのようにいたしますか = "how do you like your coffee?" Is this wrong?

Comment: @Omaewamoushindeiru It's more like 'How *would* you like your coffee?', which is a loose translation to begin with. Literally it's something like 'How shall I make your coffee for you?'

Comment: @AeonAkechi We agree. This is what I meant by 'assimilated': me or someone related to me (family, company, etc.).